# I need a much easier logic for calculating daycode in this program

Tags: c, calendar

I'm currently working on a calendar application. I got this idea from the internet,the code is given below. The formula for determining the daycode is not really easy for me to remember. So I tried implenting it in the form of for loop/while loop to calculate daycode starting from the year 0.
Note: The daycode for year 0 is 0 and year 1 is 1.
Quick Summary:
Daycode represents the first day of the year. Ranging from 0 to 6 where 0 represents Sunday and 6 represents Saturday.

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define TRUE    1
#define FALSE   0

int days_in_month[]={0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
char *months[]=
{
    " ",
    "\n\n\nJanuary",
    "\n\n\nFebruary",
    "\n\n\nMarch",
    "\n\n\nApril",
    "\n\n\nMay",
    "\n\n\nJune",
    "\n\n\nJuly",
    "\n\n\nAugust",
    "\n\n\nSeptember",
    "\n\n\nOctober",
    "\n\n\nNovember",
    "\n\n\nDecember"
};


int inputyear(void)
{
    int year;
    
    printf("Please enter a year (example: 1999) : ");
    scanf("%d", &year);
    return year;
}

int determinedaycode(int year)
{
    int daycode;
    int d1, d2, d3;
    
    d1 = (year - 1.)/ 4.0;
    d2 = (year - 1.)/ 100.;
    d3 = (year - 1.)/ 400.;
    daycode = (year + d1 - d2 + d3) %7;
    return daycode;
}


int determineleapyear(int year)
{
    if(year% 4 == FALSE && year%100 != FALSE || year%400 == FALSE)
    {
        days_in_month[2] = 29;
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        days_in_month[2] = 28;
        return FALSE;
    }
}

void calendar(int year, int daycode)
{
    int month, day;
    for ( month = 1; month <= 12; month++ )
    {
        printf("%s", months[month]);
        printf("\n\nSun  Mon  Tue  Wed  Thu  Fri  Sat\n" );
        
        // Correct the position for the first date
        for ( day = 1; day <= 1 + daycode * 5; day++ )
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        
        // Print all the dates for one month
        for ( day = 1; day <= days_in_month[month]; day++ )
        {
            printf("%2d", day );
            
            // Is day before Sat? Else start next line Sun.
            if ( ( day + daycode ) % 7 > 0 )
                printf("   " );
            else
                printf("\n " );
        }
            // Set position for next month
            daycode = ( daycode + days_in_month[month] ) % 7;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int year, daycode, leapyear;
    
    year = inputyear();
    daycode = determinedaycode(year);
    determineleapyear(year);
    calendar(year, daycode);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Problems that I'm facing from what I tried : I get the right calendar for all years except for leap years. I used a for loop for this;

```
int daycode=0;
for(int i=1;i<=year;i++)
{ if(//check for leap year) 
  {daycode++;} 
 daycode ++;} 
daycode=daycode %7;
```

Comment: "I get the right calendar for all years except for leap years." --> What was wrong with it?  2024 looks OK.  Provide details of the error seen.

Comment: Your loop `for ( day = 1; day <= 1 + daycode * 5; day++ ) { printf(" "); }` can be replaced by `printf("%*.*s", daycode * 5,  v" ");` — it takes the length as an argument.  Using the `*.*` notation works correctly when the size is 0. See also the POSIX specification for [`printf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html)
et al — though the C standard specifies the same functionalityfor this feature.

Comment: The leap year test should probably be `if ((year % 4 == FALSE && year % 100 != FALSE) || year % 400 == FALSE) {`.

Comment: @Verbatim: Since the computation `year % 4` is a number, not a boolean, it would be better to use `0` than `FALSE`, leading to `if ((year % 4 == 0) …)`.  Also, that leap year test uses division by 4 and 400 on every non-leap year.  A better test avoids the second division: `#define LEAPYEAR(y) (((y) % 4) == 0 && (((y) % 100) != 0 || ((y) % 400) == 0))` — that only divides by 100 or 400 if the year is divisible by 4.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I was offering a more accurate leap year test (by modifying the new contributor's code and since FALSE is defined as 0 at the start of the program). Yes, it is important to be careful when handling numerical expressions and booleans.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your  suggestions and answers. I found the answer to my problem. So basically whenever I entered a leap year, the for loop incremented the daycode twice. But since daycode is the day before 29th February and not after, you only had to increment the daycode once. So I had to improvise the for loop  ;

```
{ int daycode=0;
 int i=1;
for(i=1;i<=year;i++)
 { if((//check for leap year)&&(i!=year)
  daycode++;
i++;} 
daycode=daycode%7;
return daycode;
}
```

So the if condition checks not only if the year is the leap year but also checks if the entered year is a leap year. If the current year is a leap year then the daycode gets incremented only once. This condition basically works for any year until the value of I is not equal to the year entered

Answer (score 1):

I change your code to

```
int determinedaycode(int year)
{
    int daycode = 1; // assume daycode for year 1 is 1 (in fact it isn't...)

    for(int i = 1; i < year; i++) {
        if(determineleapyear(i)) {
            daycode++;
        }
        daycode ++;
    }

    daycode = daycode % 7;
    return daycode;
}
```

so that it is more clear in logic: when you calculate day code, you are basically counting the day code change (each year changes 1 since 365%7=1, leap year changes 2) BEFORE this year, so the loop should be "i < year", not "i <= year".

By the way, the code is only valid in theory...
You will need to take into account a lot of things, for example, you can google "1582 October missing 10 days".

Comment: Running `cal 9 1752` shows September skipping from 2nd to 14th  (at least in US or UK locales) — most English speaking countries didn't change from Julian to Gregorian calendar in 1582 but did in 1752 instead.  And remember that in Sweden in 1712, there was a 30th February!